# UI GameObject (Button prefab) randomly changing Z axis RectTransform when instantiated (UNITY)

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, photon

I was trying to instantiate a prefab button inside a child of canvas. It's x and y axis are staying constant but Z axis is acting weird. It becomes -800 for some reason and I can't figure out why. Here is the code:

[image]

And when I press play, here is the result:
[image]

as you can see, even though I set the rectTransform to something else, it still becomes -800 (I want it to be 0 or anything I want.). Any help would be appreciated. Thank you so much and take care.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The position you see there in the RectTransform (and Transform) is the Local Position. When you instantiate an object, and parent it to another Transform, the Local Position will be updated to keep the object in the Instantiated position. It does that by modifying the Local Position. Another way to look at it, the World Position that you instantiated the object at, is still the same after you parented it.

The `Instantiate` method has an overload that accepts a bool `InsantaiteInWorldSpace` but it looks like you want to set some positions yourself. In that case, `Transform` also has a method `SetParent` that also has an overload accepting a bool `worldPositionStays`. You can visit the Unity docs page for `SetParent` [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.SetParent.html).

In the later case, you'd not set the parent during instantiation, but afterwards, and set bool to keep the object in the position you had manually set it to. IT all depends on how you want to position your item in relation to your hierarchy.

Comment: Thank you for replying! Unfortunately, I already tried the go.transform.SetParent() and what happens is the button (which is the GO that i want to instantiate) spawns behind the canvas (in game scene) and above it in the hierarchy. I must admit that I kinda don't get some of the concepts that you said so if you don't mind educating me, I would appreciate it.

Comment: @VirtualDreamer hmmm, if it's "above" the Canvas in the hierarchy, then the parent target mustn't be correct. A child of a object would be below it in the hierarchy, and the last in the list by default. Do you want to check that the line with all those `GetChild(0)` is actually correct?

Comment: yes i did that. I used SSTools to "Toast" the name of the detected parent which it did and was correct. (RoomLayoutGroup child of the canvas in the picture)

Comment: I did try the SetParent() again and this popped up:
Setting the parent of a transform which resides in a Prefab Asset is disabled to prevent data corruption (GameObject: 'Room Button')

i did search this online and can't find a solid answer. most of them are not even close to my case

Comment: @VirtualDreamer and is your Canvas set to Screen Space - Overlay, or Screen Space Camera? If it's SS - Camera, then the -800 will cause the button to be way behind the camera. You can see it in the scene view if you take a look at the camera.

Comment: It's on SS-Overlay. I believe every canvas I have is on this setting. I did check it also

Comment: I'm not sure if this is worth mentioning but the game object (button) that I want to instantiate is a PREFAB. and in PREFAB VIEW, it has a parent gameobject named : "Canvas (Environment).

Comment: @VirtualDreamer Then the last thing I notice is well is that it looks like you have a Layout Group on the parent. I'm not sure what the settings on that are. I'm making a supposition here, but it's shouldn't be affecting the Z position, it'll position the X and Y based on what it's supposed to do. Are the setting in there correct?

Comment: Yes I do have a VerticalLayoutGroup. Here are its settings that I think is kind of related:
(btw, i don't remember changing or setting any kind of setting related to Z axis)

USE CHILD SCALE: WIDTH AND HEIGHT CHECKED
CHILD FORCE EXPAND: WIDTH AND HEIGHT CHECKED

Content Size Fitter component:

HORIZONTAL FIT: UNCONSTRAINED
VERTICAL FIT: PREFERED SIZE

Comment: I'm so sorry and you are definitely correct. Somehow, the camera was set to SS-Camera. Again I'm so sorry for wasting your time. Maybe I did not save it when I was trying to fix it. Again I apologize and really grateful for the help. I'll be better to avoid this kind of misunderstandings. Thank you so much.

Comment: @VirtualDreamer ahh! Hahaha... there you go! ;)